# Retrieve hasMany child records in route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following route:

```
/projects/5/files
```

I read in the API that using `find()` and `findAll()` will automatically update any templates that use their results when records are pushed to the store. How can I do that with the child `file` records?

Take note that the `file` records are already in the store as they are returned embedded with the project response from the server.

Currently, this is the `model` hook in my `projects/files.js` route:

```
model() {
  return this.modelFor('project').get('attachments')
}
```

This works on first load but won't update when adding records to the store afterwards.

Comment: What ember version are you working on? Did you take a look at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.FilteredRecordArray.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it **does** update!

Checkout [this ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a458cf9fcec51786e6e8?openFiles=application.route.js%2Capplication.template.hbs)!

You can not just add an attachment but also have to connect it to the project!